# Cannot specify main class for both running AND packaging jar in SBT 0.12.3

Tags: scala, sbt, typesafe-stack, typesafe

For some reason I cannot simultaneously specify main class for `run` and packaging jar in SBT 0.12.3.

The problem is that `sbt publish-local` doesn't put name of main class to jar's manifest if I don't set it explicitly.

But interestingly enough this

```
mainClass in (Compile,run) := Some("Hi")
```

and

```
mainClass in (Compile,packageBin) := Some("Hi")
```

work separately but this

```
mainClass in (Compile,run,packageBin) := Some("Hi")
```

causes SBT fail with following error

```
C:\work\test_projects\hw\build.sbt:13: error: reassignment to val
mainClass in (run,Compile,packageBin) := Some("Hi")
                                      ^
[error] Type error in expression
```

Is it a bug or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `(Compile,run)` in

```
mainClass in (Compile,run) := Some("Hi")
```

is specifying the two axes of the four axes that a setting has, so `(Compile,run,packageBin)` doesn't make sense. If you want to grab the value from the other, you could say:

```
mainClass in (Compile,packageBin) <<= mainClass in (Compile,run)
```

For more details, check out [Getting Started guide](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Getting-Started/More-About-Settings.html#computing-a-value-based-on-other-keys-values).